# Deleting a value in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, append

I've created an array for my output by doing this:

```
for i in nameList
    test_array.append({'Name': i, 'Email': memberMail, 'Department': memberDepartment})
```

However, later in the code, I must remove designated values in my `test_array` depending on their email. After that, I can easily print out what I need to my csv file.

How do I delete a specific entry from this sort of dictionary list?

*For those curious, when I print the array currently it looks like this:*

```
[{'Department': 'Public Works', 'Email': 'joe@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Joe'}, {'Department': 'Infrastructure', 'Email': 'bob@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Bob'}, {'Department': 'IT', 'Email': 'suzanne@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Suzanne'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For when you not want to modify `test_array`

```py
filtered_test_array = filter(lambda entry: entry['Email'] != 'email@example.com', test_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for i in range(0,len(nameList)):
        if nameList[i]['Email'] == 'abc@pqr.com" :
             index = i;

    del nameList[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
list_ = [{'Department': 'Public Works', 'Email': 'joe@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Joe'}, {'Department': 'Infrastructure', 'Email': 'bob@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Bob'}, {'Department': 'IT', 'Email': 'suzanne@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Suzanne'}]
for val in list_:
    if val['Email'] == 'joe@xyz.gov':
        list_.remove(val)
```

**Result**

```
[{'Department': 'Infrastructure', 'Email': 'bob@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Bob'},
 {'Department': 'IT', 'Email': 'suzanne@xyz.gov', 'Name': 'Suzanne'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list and delete with respect to a unique value or a key. Something like this:

```
for entry in test_array:
    if entry['Email'] == 'suzanne@xyz.gov':
        test_array.remove(entry)
```